# how to add form input over slider banner?

Tags: html, css

Code:

```
<section id="featured" class="bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="main-slider" class="main-slider flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                      <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/slides/flexslider/1.jpg" alt="" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/slides/flexslider/2.jpg" alt="" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/slides/flexslider/3.jpg" alt="" />
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>

<input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" placeholder="Search Your Result">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="search">
```

In my code I have a slider banner where three images are sliding simultaneously where I want to add form input or search bar over slider i.e. image of slider moving but search bar should be fix. So, How can I do this ?Please help me or share reference.

Thank You

Comment: Maybe take a look at css position and x-index

Comment: add form as `overlay` over image.

Comment: Just place the inputs in a `<div class="row">` before the slider row?

Answer (score 0):

use `positions` rules to position the inputs on top of slider.

```js
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false
  });
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.inputs-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.flex-direction-nav {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.4/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.4/flexslider.min.css" tpye="text/css">
<section id="featured" class="bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 slider-wrapper">
                <div id="main-slider" class="main-slider flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                      <li>
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150.jpg" alt="" />
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="inputs-wrapper">
                  <input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" placeholder="Search Your Result">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="search">                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap's input group. And remember to place this whole block of code inside your `<form>` tag.

```
<section id="featured" class="bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bar" id="bar" placeholder="Search Your Result">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-light" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
                            Search
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="main-slider" class="main-slider flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/slides/flexslider/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/slides/flexslider/2.jpg" alt="" />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resources/img/slides/flexslider/3.jpg" alt="" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>
```